# Open Maps between topological spaces

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, continuity

Let $X,Y$ be topological spaces. A map $f$ from $X$ to $Y$ is open if for every open set $U$ in $X$ , $f(U)$ is open in $Y$.
Let $X= \mathbb{R}$ and $Y= \mathbb{S^1}$ 
and  $f: t \rightarrow e^{2\pi i t}$
our condition for $f$ being open is really the same as $f^{-1}$ being continuous. $f^{-1}: t \rightarrow \frac{log(t)}{2\pi i} $ where we've defined a continuous branch of log on the complex plane. So since $f^{-1}$ is cont the map f is cont.
Would appreciate verfication that this is ok.

Comment: What I would try is to show $f$ sends (small) open intervals onto open arcs on the sphere (which arcs exactly?), and open arcs are the basic neighbourhoods of $S^1$.

Comment: @JonSK  I now understand your way

Answer (score 1):

This is not okay, sorry. The function $f$ is clearly not injective ($f(t)=f(t+1)$). Therefore, we cannot find an inverse of $f$. The function you found is also not continuous either. No matter which branch you choose, you will run into a problem if you try to define it over the entire unit circle. Some of your ideas are salvagable, though. Your "inverse" is a local inverse which is continuous over proper subsets of the unit circle. Prove that every open subset of $\mathbb R$ is the union of open intervals with width less than $1$, and then show using your local inverse that these sets are the images of proper subsets of the unit circle.

Comment: When you say proper subsets of the unit circle- do they have to be open?

Comment: Nope. As long as the set $A\subset S^1$ does not contain every point of the unit circle, we can find a branch cut so that the local inverse is continuous (we just cut along the line containing a point not in $A$). This does not mean that $f^{-1}(A)$ is open. It just means that if $B\subset A$ is open in $S^1$, then $f^{-1}(B)$ is open.